# Как ускорить работу c mysql при большом количестве операций записи?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю сервис на php, в основном ничего сложного, загружаем в базу *(mysql)* записи, делаю 1 curl запрос на каждую запись и записываю результат в бд.

И все работало отлично, до тех пор покуда не потребовалось работать с базой объемом в 20 млн записей.

Сейчас все записи пишет в одну таблицу. При запуске скрипта я формирую массив из всех данных из таблицы (20 млн. строк) и после этого делю этот массив на 20 частей. Затем я запускаю 20 одинаковых php скриптов

```
shell_exec("php script.php $array_part")
```

и каждый скрипт делает запросы с помощью `curl_multi_init()` на нужный мне API *(он платный, поэтому ограничений по кол-ву запросов и частоте нету)*, после полученный результат записываю в базу.

Так как `curl_multi_init()` делает сразу несколько запросов (поставили 200), быстро приходит много ответов (~200*20=4000), и на каждый ответ нужно сделать запись в базу и несколько обновлений уже существующих записей. И вот здесь базе данных очень тяжко работать, несмотря на ее оптимизацию, индексы и тд.

Сервер имеет 14гб ОЗУ, 8 процессоров, но все равно видны заметные фризы в момент работы php скриптов с большим объемом данных одновременно.

Как правильно работать с такими большими таблицами (когда нужно 1 раз прочитать и на каждую полученную запись делать ~2 update и 1 insert)?

Может быть создать несколько таблиц которые делать записи четные/нечетные? или как-то еще разделять? Но на запись же от этого серверу по идее легче не станет, так как все пишет в одну БД...

Разбивать базу данные на несколько серверов? по какому принципу делить данные...?

Буду очень благодарен за ответы!

P.S. очень важна скорость обработки данных, поэтому уменьшить число одновременно запускаемых php скриптов нет возможности.

Comment: что у вас за бд? (mysql, postgresql ..?). Вы смотрели в сторону использование worker?

Comment: @user334685 бд mysql . нет, есть какие-то примеры или как их найти?

Comment: по бд, лучше, наверное, использовать что-то типа clickhouse. как раз предназначен для вставки многомиллионных записей. По воркерам, это аналог вашего shell_exec. Погуглите. Принцип простой, к вам приходит ответ от curl, вы кидаете этот ответ в очередь, в очереди уже происходит вставки, обновление записей в бд. Т.е. у вас будет создаваться многопоточность воркерами. Но при этом каждый воркер - это отдельный php процесс, грубо говоря. Но воркеу может и не решат вашу задачу, все-таки основная проблема это фризы бд mysql.

Comment: какого типа поля в таблице обновляются?

Comment: @sterx int и varchar

Comment: дробить таблицу не пробовали? выносить varchar в отдельную со связкой по внешнему ключу

Comment: вам прям все 20млн надо прочитать и по ним запросы сделать? эт что за предметная область такая и задача? тут бы считывать порцию данных из таблицы. делать запросы куда надо. результаты складывать в буфер. Потом из буфера забирать пачкой и вставлять/апдейтить в базу также пачкой. Индексы для вставки и апдейта ничего не ускоряют, а лишь наборот лишнюю работу делают их при данных операциях актуализировать надо. Если есть вариант партциирования таблицы - то можете партицировать. Хотя еще вопрос объема данных. 20млн записей может занимать и 2 гигабайта и 200.

Comment: @teran да, по всем 20млн делаем запросы. сервис для внутреннего использования сотрудниками компании. проверяем данные. про считывание порции данных, вы имели ввиду взять например 1млн, их проверить и брать следующий млн? тогда нужно делать поле, например `check` и проверенным делать update запрос и ставить 1, и когда выбираем следующую партию мы делаем where `check` = 0. так имели ввиду?

Comment: @iKey смотрели в сторону написать бэк на sql(функции, правила), а не на php? возможно, это разгрузит , и партиции примерить. Для корпаративного приложения с сотрудниками там скорее всего временной интервал есть 3 месяца или  пол года или вообще месяц, если вы за 10 лет (утрирую) каждый раз лопатите тьму данных, то это печально и где-то кто-то оступился. Если все эти манипуляции вам нужны для аналитики "онлайн", то mysql не лучшее решение. если вы на этапе только планирования своего приложения, посмотрите в сторону postgreSQL.

Comment: "При запуске скрипта я формирую массив из всех данных из таблицы (20 млн. строк) и после этого делю этот массив на 20 частей. Затем я запускаю 20 одинаковых php скриптов" - мне кажется все это противоречит условию "быстро". Во-первых, что будет в вашем сценарии, если в какой-то момент прерывается соединение и часть ваших скриптов не может выполнить curl-запросы? Сеть лагает или целевой сервис недоступен? Начнете сначала или что?

Comment: Во-вторых, как я понял, php отрабатывает быстро и начинает пачками из 20 параллельно запущенных скриптов обновлять базу. Это приводит к конкуренции на время блокировок (а блокировки у вас есть при вставке и обновлении данных). Т.е. одновременно работающие php-скрипты еще и конкурируют за БД, что довольно печально. Т.е. очень хочется написать, что задачу прогона и обновления таблицы в несколько десятков миллионов записей решать быстро очень сомнительная идея в целом. Я бы думал в сторону очередей и для запуска запросов (если не можем выполнить curl)

Comment: И очередей для обработки результатов. По части партиций.... Не зная в чем суть проекта в целом трудно подсказывать, но если вдруг вы  можете делить физически данные на сегменты для партиций, вдруг вы можете их делить и на шарды? Тогда, как вариант, можно думать в сторону того, чтобы разделить большую (и возможно растущую и далее) таблицу на шарды между несколькими инстансами БД

Comment: Вам нужно перевести таблицы в формат хранения данных InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

#### Оптимизация записи

Самое первое, на что следует обращать внимание при проблемах  множественной записи - это значение переменной **`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`**, поскольку она может замедлять запись в **десятки** раз.

И далее смотреть по обостоятельствам.
В вашем случае, как я понимаю, безопасно поставить `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`. Это сразу повысит скорость в десятки раз.

Если хочется использовать другие значения, то можно собирать запросы в блоки, и записывать большими партиями - либо через INSERT с множеством VALUES, либо заключая пачки отдельных запросов в одну транзакцию.

#### Оптимизация работы с БД

Кроме того, просто закидать БД железом недостаточно. Им надо с умом воспользоваться. В частности настраивать буфера, и в первую очередь - `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Если в нем стоит значение по умолчанию, то разницы будет ни с 4, ни с 14, ни со 140 гигами памяти. Под этот буфер надо отводить 80-90% памяти на сервере.

Плюс все эти общие слова - "индексы, шминдексы, оптимизация" - это разговор ни о чем. Надо конкретно смотреть, какие индексы, какая оптимизация, в каком месте тормозит. И приходить уже с конкретными вопросами.

#### Партиционирование

При больших объемах данных (начиная от миллионов строк) следует подумать о партиционировании. Это разбиение таблиц на части средствами самой БД, прозрачно для приложения.

#### Платная поддержка

В России это не принято, но на самом деле это очень умный вариант.
Вместо того чтобы самим биться как рыба об лед, и вместо того чтобы спрашивать совета у непонятных людей в интернете, можно купить консультационные услуги одной из многочисленных компаний, которые развивают форки mysql - MariaDB, Percona, Mysql AB. Это, собственно, их заработок, благодаря которому данные СУБД и развиваются. То есть вы поможете одновременно и себе, и поддержите разработку открытого программного обеспечения.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что у автора высокая нагрузка на базу данных? У него могут выполняться долго скрипты или вообще 50% времени уходит на подключение к базе данных.

Comment: @Mcile я прочитал вопрос.

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужно перевести таблицы в формат хранения данных InnoDB
InnoDB более надежна при больших объемах данных.
InnoDB в теории немного быстрее.

Также вам нужно иметь постоянное подключение к базе данных - если вы будете обращаться к базе несколько раз за сеанс - постоянное обращение к базе сэкономит вам время.
Если есть возможность, разместите выполняемый скрипт на том же железе, где хранится база данных, чтобы не тратить время на подключение и не ограничиваться скоростью периферийных устройств.
Можно также рассмотреть NoSQL базу с горизонтальным расширением - хранить куски базы на разных серверах.

Comment: Извините, но это больше напоминает рекомендации chatGPT. К примеру, совершенно непонятно, при чем тут внешние ключи. Или каким образом постоянное соединение поможет снизить нагрузку на БД вообще, и каким местом оно относится к данной конкретной проблеме в частности. Такое ощущение, что это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос.

Comment: постоянное соединение не снизит нагрузку на базу данных, а снизит время выполнения скрипта

Comment: Не смешите пожалуйста. Во-первых, снижение там будет микроскопическое. А во-вторых, и самых главных - здесь нет вопроса "как снизить время выполнения скрипта". А только "как снизить нагрузку на базу данных"

Comment: Смотрите, я уверен что вы тоже сможете понять этот вопрос, если дадите себе труд прочитать его, там ничего сложного: "я запускаю 20 одинаковых php скриптов, и каждый скрипт делает запросы". Как видно, каждый скрипт обрабатывает по миллиону записей. И время, которое этот скрипт тратит на то чтобы *один разв в самом начале* соединиться базой, будет будет последним в причин низкой производительности. Нет, автор конечно может соединяться для выполнения каждого запроса, но в этом случае ему надо выпрямлять руки и использовать одно нормальное соединение, а не городить постоянное.